# Apply Guava Range min/max

Tags: java, range, guava

I have a [Guava Range](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) with upper and lower bounds:

```
Integer upper = 5;
Integer lower = 3;
Range<Integer> range = Range.closed(lower,upper);
```

I have values that I wish to be within the given range similar to Math.min and Math.max:

```
Integer above = 6;
Integer within = 4;
Integer below = 2;

assert range.apply(above) == upper;
assert range.apply(below) == lower;
assert range.apply(within) == within;
```

Range.apply implements the Predicate.apply so the above code doesn't compile, but I'm looking for the equivalent method in some utility or otherwise that will give me the value given if it is within the bounds or return the nearest bound endpoint if not.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own utility method:

```
/**
 * Ensures the value given is with the range or returns the nearest boundary endpoint.
 * 
 * WARNING: This only works with closed ranges.  
 * Open ranges will return an endpoint that will return false from Range.contains().
 * @param range
 * @param value
 * @return
 */
@Nonnull
public static <C extends Comparable<C>> C apply(@Nonnull Range<C> range, @Nonnull C value) {
    C result;
    if (value == null || range.contains(value)) {
        result = value;
    } else if (range.hasLowerBound() && range.lowerEndpoint().compareTo(value) >= 0) {
        result = range.lowerEndpoint();
    } else if (range.hasUpperBound() && range.upperEndpoint().compareTo(value) <= 0) {
        result = range.upperEndpoint();
    } else {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Range should contain or violate one of the bounds " + range + " for "
                + value);
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm hoping Guava already provides this method or some alternative.